# Mask 8 Integers in the middle of a 16 length integer with * (Credit Card numbers)

Tags: regex, splunk

I need to extract and mask the middle 8 integers from a 16 digit number and mask them.

---

E.g.:

```
1759759473504563
```

End result:

```
1759********4563
```

In case it helps in any way I need it to help mask credit card numbers in Splunk.

Comment: Sorry I don't know about splunk but I know a little bit about regex. The regex for a 16 digit number string that captures the middle 8 digit is `/^\d{4}(\d{8})\d{4}$/`.  If I could use JavaScript, then to extract the middle 8 digit I would do `/^\d{4}(\d{8})\d{4}$/.exec(str)[1]` and to mask the middle middle 8 digit I would do `str.slice(0,4) + "*".repeat(8) + str.slice(-4)`. Here `str` is the card number string.

Comment: This is a sample problem given in the Splunk documentation - https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/StreamProcessor/standard/Tutorial/MaskCC & https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/Anonymizedata. And here on Answers.Splunk: https://community.splunk.com/t5/Getting-Data-In/How-to-mask-emails-and-credit-card-numbers-in-logs/m-p/200503

Comment: You should never log sensitive information.  
You should only be logging masked credit card numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Splunk uses PCRE Regex. Have a try with

```
(?:\b\d{4}(?=\d{12}\b)\K|\G\B)\d(?=\d{4})
```

and use `*` or whatever you like as replacement - [See this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/6BmA6p/3).

The idea is to use the [`\G` anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) for chaining matches and [`\K` to reset](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K).

- `\b\d{4}(?=\d{12}\b)\K` is used to find an entry point for  the chain:
  `\b` a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (*zero-width*) and matching `\d{4}` four digits
  `(?=\d{12}\b` [if followed by](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)  12 digits - `\K` resets the reported match.
- `|\G\B` the right side of the alternation is to `\G` chain matches at `\B`
  which is a *non word boundary* to prevent `\G` from matching at start.

This will only work, if `\G` and `\K` are supported in Splunk's replace-function.